# mem (MB) res:0 virt:0 mapped:0

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to install mongodb on my windows xp system and all i can see is installation doesnt move ahead .. can some one help on getting mongodb installed?

```
mongod.exe --dbpath d:\xx\Mongodb\Mongodb\data
Fri Jun 29 18:33:21
Fri Jun 29 18:33:21 warning: 32-bit servers don't have journaling enabled by default. Please use --journal if you want durability.
Fri Jun 29 18:33:21
Fri Jun 29 18:33:21 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=3568 port=27017 dbpath=d:\xx\Mongodb\Mongodb\data 32-bit host=admin1
Fri Jun 29 18:33:21 [initandlisten]
Fri Jun 29 18:33:21 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: when using MongoDB 32 bit, you are limited to about 2 gigabytes of data
Fri Jun 29 18:33:21 [initandlisten] **       see http://blog.mongodb.org/post/137788967/32-bit-limitations
Fri Jun 29 18:33:21 [initandlisten] **       with --journal, the limit is lower
Fri Jun 29 18:33:21 [initandlisten]
Fri Jun 29 18:33:21 [initandlisten] db version v2.0.6, pdfile version 4.5
Fri Jun 29 18:33:21 [initandlisten] git version: e1c0cbc25863f6356aa4e31375add7bb49fb05bc
Fri Jun 29 18:33:21 [initandlisten] build info: windows sys.getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=0, build=6002, platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 2') BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_42
Fri Jun 29 18:33:21 [initandlisten] options: { dbpath: "d:\xx\Mongodb\Mongodb\data" }
Fri Jun 29 18:33:21 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Fri Jun 29 18:33:21 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
Fri Jun 29 18:34:21 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:14 virt:46 mapped:0
Fri Jun 29 18:39:21 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:14 virt:46 mapped:0
Fri Jun 29 18:40:21 [PeriodicTask::Runner] task: DBConnectionPool-cleaner took:15ms
Fri Jun 29 18:44:21 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:0 virt:46 mapped:0
Fri Jun 29 18:49:21 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:0 virt:46 mapped:0
Fri Jun 29 18:54:21 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:0 virt:46 mapped:0
Fri Jun 29 18:59:21 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:0 virt:46 mapped:0
Fri Jun 29 19:04:21 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:0 virt:46 mapped:0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normal MongoDB output. You can tell from the line `Fri Jun 29 18:33:21 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017` that mongod has started up and is awaiting connections.

If you want to install MongoDB as a windows service, you can do so using `mongod.exe [options] --install`; see more options in the [MongoDB manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongod.exe/).

Regarding the last few lines in the output, those simply mean that MongoDB hasn't yet loaded any data files into memory. As you create or use data, the numbers there will change to indicate how much resident (i.e. in physical RAM), virtual, and mapped memory mongod is using.